# Manipulate parameters with parameter ranges dependent on other parameters

Tags: manipulate

I've reduced some of my code to the code here

```
Manipulate[
(*output here here*)
{j, 1, 40, 1},
{k, 1, Dynamic[j], 1},
]
```

The problem I'd like to fix is that if I set j to 40, then k to 35, and then set j down to 20, a bunch of errors get thrown. Is there a way to add something to the code here that when j gets updated k gets reset to 1?

Comment: try replacing `{j, 1, 40, 1}` with `{j, 1, 40, 1, TrackingFunction -> (j = #; k = 1; &)}`?

Comment: .. or with `{j, 1, 40, 1, TrackingFunction -> (j = #; k = Min[#, k]; &)}` to reset `k` to `j` when `j` moves below current value of `k` (as in Nasser's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by error, you mean you get this red marking.

[image]

This just says upper limit of slider is reached. You can throttle this like this

```
Manipulate[
 If[k > j, k = j];
 Row[{"j=", j, ", k=", k}],
 {{j, 1, "j"}, 1, 40, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 1, "k"}, 1, Dynamic[j], 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {j, k}
 ]
```

And now if upper limit for `k` is more than `j`, it will go to match `j`.

You should also always add `TrackedSymbols`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using an explicit [`Dynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) is not necessary.

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 k = Min[k, j];
 StringForm["j = ``; k = ``", j, k],
 {{j, 20}, 1, 40, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k, 10}, 1, j, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {j, k}]
```